# Jquery sum of parent and his childs in new row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have basic html table structure (table, tr, td) of projects costs. Some projects contains subprojects (subprojects contains img attribute).

I'm wondering how it's possible to dynamically add a new row that sums up values per each column (all months and totals) for parent (Project) and his childs (subproject) based on img attribute which is in every child element.

Current State:

[image: Current state]]

What I want:

[image: My wish]]

I tried with jQuery map function but without success.
Please help me out.

```
<table cellspacing='15'>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Project</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sep</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Totals</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <td>Project 1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>78</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Project 2</td>
    <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>78</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src='http://healthsidekick.com/chat71/mobile-client/img/icon-go-arrow.png'></img>Subproject 1 of Proejct 2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0.6</td>
        <td>0.7</td>
        <td>0.8</td>
        <td>0.9</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0.1</td>
        <td>0.11</td>
        <td>0.12</td>
        <td>0.13</td>
        <td>0.14</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>7.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src='http://healthsidekick.com/chat71/mobile-client/img/icon-go-arrow.png'></img>Subproject 2 of Proejct 2</td>
        <td>0.9</td>
        <td>0.6</td>
        <td>0.7</td>
        <td>0.8</td>
        <td>0.9</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0.1</td>
        <td>0.2</td>
        <td>0.3</td>
        <td>0.4</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
        <td>0.6</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Proejct 3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>—</td>
        <td>—</td>
        <td>—</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>—</td>
        <td>—</td>
        <td>—</td>
        <td>—</td>
        <td>—</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFIDDLE link to table structure](http://jsfiddle.net/08osno5n)

Comment: Can you please add your HTML to the question, along with any attempts you've made to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: What good is this image to us helping solve your problem? Share your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/08osno5n/
Image would help you to get all subprojects (for example, we can use find function to get all images and based on that all subprojects and their parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a simpler solution but I did my best. This what you can use:

```
var results = [],
    insertResultsAfter = [],
    trIndex;
$('table tr').each(function(index, value){
    if ($(this).find('td:first').text().trim().substring(0, 7) == 'Project') {
        trIndex = index;
        results[trIndex] = [];
        $(this).find('td').each(function(tdIndex, value){
            results[trIndex].push(parseFloat($(this).text()));
            insertResultsAfter[trIndex] = trIndex;
        });
    } else if ($(this).find('td:first').text().trim().substring(0, 10) == 'Subproject') {
        $(this).find('td').each(function(tdIndex, value){
            results[trIndex][tdIndex] += parseFloat($(this).text());
        });
        insertResultsAfter[trIndex] = index;
    }
});

var addedToIndex = 0;
for (var key in results) {
    $tr = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('bg').insertAfter($('table tr:eq(' + (insertResultsAfter[key] + addedToIndex) + ')'));
    $.each(results[key], function(index2, valueForEachTd) {
        $('<td></td>').text(valueForEachTd.toFixed(2)).appendTo($tr);
    });
    addedToIndex++;
}
```

[The updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/08osno5n/1/)